# How to lock a dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a static dictionary in a multi thread application.
class A Reads the dictionary and class B Removes from it.
I want to lock dictionary when removing from it or reading from it to prevent accessing problems to it in concurrency situations.
How can I Lock the dictionary?

```
    public static Dictionary<string, Thread> DicThreads = new Dictionary<string, Thread>();
    Class A()
    {
     private void MethodA()
    {
if (DicThreads.ContainsKey(key))
       if (DicThreads[key] == null || DicThreads[key].ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
    {
     //--- Do something
    }
    }


    class B
    {
      private void MethodB()
    {
       DicThreads.Remove(key)
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't use `ConcurrentDictionary`?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're using .NET 4 or higher, go for COncurrentDictionary

Comment: @pwas you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @sharpcloud question was about locking casual dictionary - I've posted an alternative with single link, so I don't think it would be a good answer :)

Comment: @pwas of course, but it's a really nice alternative to locking the full dictionary. Using the best tools for the job, and such :) It's pretty common for developers to stare blindly at they're current solution, while a better although different approach is available.

Comment: Why don't you swap to using BackgroundWorkers and handle RunWorkerCompleted event instead of tracking thread state manually?  Or tasks and the continuewith?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary` as pwas suggests. If you want to synchronise the dictionary that you have, you use the `lock` keyword.

You should generally use a separate object for the synchronising, and don't expose that object outside your scope. That ensures that code outside the block can't use the same object for locks and cause conflicts.

```
public static Dictionary<string, Thread> DicThreads = new Dictionary<string, Thread>();
private static object sync = new Object();

Class A() {

  private void MethodA() {
    lock (sync) {
      if (DicThreads.ContainsKey(key)) {
        if (DicThreads[key] == null || DicThreads[key].ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped) {
          //--- Do something
        }
      }
    }
  }

}

class B {

  private void MethodB() {
    lock (sync) {
      DicThreads.Remove(key)
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`lock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

```
lock (DicThreads)
{
   // Any code here is synchronized with other
   // (including this block on other threads)
   // lock(DicThreads) blocks
}
```

---

However, if you have a dictionary of threads in your application, you are probably doing it wrong. Read all about the [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Stephen Cleary has wirtten a useful `AsyncCollection<T>` class](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncCollection). Available in the Nito.AsyncEx package on NuGet.

If you need an asynchronous collection its a good candidate, it actually takes a ConcurrentBag/Stack/Queue or some other `IProducerConsumerCollection` to provide backing state.

Remember, as stated, you should not be managing the threads yourself, as illustrated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ConcurrentDictionary<T>`.